# Regex expression similar to WordPress shortcodes

Tags: php, regex, shortcode

I have read the other threads with similar problems. But none specific to this case - what if I have shortcodes of the same kind enclosed in the main shortcode

So this is the demo shortcode - http://regexr.com/3a1r6

Input

```
[cigar] [cigar] [cigar] ceva [/cigar] [/cigar] [/cigar] ceva [cigar] [cigar] [cigar] alceva [/cigar] [/cigar] [/cigar]
```

Test regex

```
\[cigar].*?\[\/cigar\]
```

The correct output would be -

```
[cigar] [cigar] [cigar] ceva [/cigar] [/cigar] [/cigar]
```

not

```
[cigar] [cigar] [cigar] ceva [/cigar]
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: post the input and  your regex here.

Comment: it was on that link but ok, ok posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a negative lookahead assertion like below,

```
\[cigar].*?\[\/cigar\](?!\s*\[\/)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hJ5zN6/2)

`(?!\s*\[\/)` Negative lookahead asserts that the match would be followed by any but not of one or more spaces and further followed by  `[/` symbols.

Comment: Thanks @Raj

Any solution for this string ?

[cigar] [cigar] [cigar] ceva [/cigar] [/cigar] [/cigar]  [cigar] [cigar] [cigar] alceva [/cigar] [/cigar] [/cigar]

?

Comment: it turns out as 1 match and it should be 2

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing, it doesn't matter.

Let's say I'm writing a BBCode parser, and I have this to deal with:
`[b] [b] [b] Triple bold for some reason! [/b] [/b] [/b]`

So I have a regex, say `/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/` => `"<b>$1</b>"`

If I *repeatedly apply the replacement until it doesn't change anything any more*, the result is:
`<b> <b> <b> Triple bold for some reason! </b> </b> </b>`

As far as the browser is concerned, I have three perfectly valid nested elements, even though when I was parsing them I wasn't doing it from the outside inwards.

---

Another alternative is to match from the last one to the first. This would be done with
`/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\](?!.*\[b\])/`

This will match the last `[b]`, and the first `[/b]` that follows it - in other words, the innermost nested pair. Again, repeated application until nothing changes will result in all pairs being parsed, but this time they will actually be parsed in the "right" order. (Note that the above regex may be slow or inefficient on large inputs - use with care)